# Why is bootstrap script not working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

If I go to the jumbotron bootstrap example, the scripts are not working when I press the "Learn more" and "View details" buttons:

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/

Shouldn't the buttons do something? Why doesn't it work? I tried both in google chrome and in internet explorer.

Shouldn't the clicks expand a text?

Comment: The buttons do do something, they take you to the same URL with a # on the end. I'm using Firefox BTW. Just tried in Chrome, that works too.

Comment: The buttons don't actually lead anywhere. It is just an example of using `.jumbotron`, not of how to build an entire site using Bootstrap.

Comment: Shouldn't the clicks expand a text?

Comment: @Programmer400 Nope. They're just links to another page (which in this case is just an anchor on the same page). But it is possible to make them "expand a text" using Bootstrap (just not in this example).